# In Karger's min cut algorithm, eliminating self-loops in a graph

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory, kargers-algorithm

I'm trying to implement [Karger's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karger%27s_algorithm) for finding the minimum cut of a graph. The key part is the `contract` method which performs a single contraction. Here is my implementation so far (with a 'test'):

```
import pytest
import random


class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self, G):
        self.G = G      # Adjacency list

    @property
    def edges(self):
        E = list()
        for vertex in self.G:
            for adjacent_vertex in self.G[vertex]:
                if vertex < adjacent_vertex:
                    E.append([vertex, adjacent_vertex])
        return E

    def randomized_contract(self):
        edge = random.choice(self.edges)
        self.contract(edge)

    def contract(self, edge):
        vertex, adjacent_vertex = edge
        self.G[vertex].remove(adjacent_vertex)
        self.G[adjacent_vertex].remove(vertex)
        self.G[vertex] += self.G[adjacent_vertex]
        del self.G[adjacent_vertex]
        for v in self.G:
            for n, av in enumerate(self.G[v]):
                if av == adjacent_vertex:
                    self.G[v][n] = vertex
        self.remove_self_loops()

    def remove_self_loops(self):
        for vertex in self.G:
            for n, adjacent_vertex in enumerate(self.G[vertex]):
                if adjacent_vertex == vertex:
                    del self.G[vertex][n]

    def contract_till_cut(self):
        while len(self.G) > 2:
            self.randomized_contract()


def test_contract_till_cut():
    graph = Graph({1: [2,3], 2: [1,3], 3: [1,2,4], 4: [3]})
    graph.contract_till_cut()
    print(graph.G)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main([__file__, "-s"])
```

My problem is that on one particular run (you might have to run it a few times to reproduce this result), the get the adjacency list

```
{1: [1, 4], 4: [1]}
```

where node 1 has a 'self-loop' - that is, it occurs in its own adjacency list. I don't see how this can happen; every call to `contract` is topped off by a call to `remove_self_loops` which seems to work. Can anyone spot the bug in this code?

Comment: I suggest using the Kruskal-like implementation with a union-find structure instead of doing actual contractions.  It's much faster, and easier too.  1) put each edge in its own set.  2) walk through the edges in random order merging the sets connected by each edge until there are only 2 sets.  3) Then the remaining edges that connect the 2 sets are  the cut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the `remove_self_loops` method: it was terminating after remove only one self-loop. I replaced it by the following:

```
def remove_self_loops(self):
    for vertex in self.G:
        self.G[vertex] = [av for av in self.G[vertex] if not av == vertex]
```

Now after the 'problem' case (which corresponds to contracting along edges `[1,2]` and `[1,3]` consecutively) I get the expected (minimum) cut:

```
{1: [4], 4: [1]}
```